# JDBC Delete Query with multiple conditions

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have been struggling with an SQL Delete query. I want it to delete a row, Where 2 conditions are met. The error I am getting says my SQL Syntax is wrong near the end at the last ')'.

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM course 
              WHERE (username_entry = " + username + 
            " AND course_name = " + courseToDelete.toUpperCase() + ")";
```

My variables have the right values and the data in the database corresponds perfectly.

Comment: You are missing quotes, use prepared statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of what your raw query might look like:

```
DELETE
FROM course
WHERE username_entry = tim AND course_name = chemistry;
```

Of course, this is not valid SQL, because you are comparing text columns against what will be perceived as other columns called `tim` and `chemistry`.  You really want the above query to look like this:

```
DELETE
FROM course
WHERE username_entry = 'tim' AND course_name = 'chemistry';
```

In other words, you need to compare against properly escaped string literals.  But in practice, the best thing to do is to use prepared statements, which handle the formatting automatically:

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM course WHERE username_entry = ? AND course_name = ?";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, username);
ps.setString(2, courseToDelete.toUpperCase());
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the extremely fast response. I tried doing it with PreparedStatement actually but got confused. It's my first day actively using JDBC for my final project for the semester. Thank you very much once again.

Answer (score -1):

You need to encapsulate string values into quotes

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM course 
              WHERE (username_entry = '" + username + 
            "' AND course_name = '" + courseToDelete.toUpperCase() + "')";
```

But better way is to use prepared statements as they do automatical escape

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to use any open / close paranthesis for the query as such!

As suggested in the other answers, you don't really need to use the injection of variables but instead, use the `PreparedStatement`

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM course 
          WHERE username_entry = '" + username + 
        "' AND course_name = '" + courseToDelete +"'";
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You dont have to use paranthesis, but those doesnt cause sintaxis error. I believe the problem is the missing quotes for string.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to remove the braces after the Where clause.

The query would look like below after the change:

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM course 
          WHERE username_entry = '" + username + 
        "' AND course_name = '" + courseToDelete.toUpperCase()+"'";
```